# Gamemaker 2 Programming language

Tags: programming-languages

Which programming language using by gamemaker 2?

I'm kinda new programming and I want it to start with gamemaker 2

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://gamemaker.io/en/gamemaker/features It says "GML": https://manual.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGameMaker_Language_Index.htm

Answer (score 0):

GameMaker Studio 2 uses GML which is a proprietary language.
If you are already familiar with Javascript, you'll find tons of similarities. As of GameMaker Studio 2.3+, GML has pretty much all the features native in Javascript.

PS: I'm a GML user for 8+ years.